# script inlcudes unit in multiplication

Tags: javascript, html

I only want to show the '$' as a unit on a text area. I have this code to display the value of an option which is a price of a product and display it with a unit.
html

```
<input type="Number" name="Quantity" min="0" max="24" name="Quantity">
<option>
              <option value="20.25" >Sugar & Moss</option>
              <option value="23.25" >Black Fig</option>
              <option value="19.25" >Sandalwood Rose</option>
              <option value="25.10" >Golden Coast</option>
              <option value="24.15" >Piñion</option>
</option>
<textarea name="unit" id="Unit_Price"></textarea>
<textarea name="SubTotal" id="SubTotal"></textarea>
```

```
function myFunction(){
    var price document.getElementById("option").value;
    document.getElementById("Unit_Price").innerHTML = '$' + price;
```

however, when I try to get the subtotal by multiplying it to quantity using another function, it also multiply the '$' symbol. if I add it on the `textarea` itself, it disappears since the value is changed.

```
function SubTotal(){
    var x = document.getElementById("Quantity").value;
    var y = document.getElementById("Unit_Price").value;
    document.getElementById("SubTotal").innerHTML = '$'+(x * y)
```

Comment: May you share a [mcve]? It would be good to see the HTML too

Comment: You have to remove the `$` before you try to use it as a number.

Comment: @evolutionxbox there, I added what i think is necessary as to not bloat the question.

Comment: `document.getElementById("SubTotal").innerHTML = '$'+(+x * +y.substring(1))`

Comment: @Barmar how do i do that without removing it on unit price?

Comment: I suggest you don't put `$` in the textarea in the first place. Put it in the HTML right before the textarea. `$ <textarea id="Unit_Price">...</textarea>`

Comment: @Barmar but that would be outside the field of textarea?

Comment: Yes, that's the whole point. The textarea should just contain the price, not extra text.

Comment: Also, why are you using a textarea for a single number, instead of `<input type="text">`?

Comment: because I'd only display the value and I don't see it as an input. I'm only a student and I didn't know which is proper. thank you anyways.